# WebDriverThread.getDriver() - Error creating the driver error while starting Selenium as systemctl service

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, systemctl

The below is my JSON file chrome node:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "webdriver.chrome.driver": "/home/node1/seleniumserver/chromedriver",
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "version": 2.39,
      "deviceName": "chrome"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 100,
  "timeout": 1500,
  "port": 4502,
  "host": "10.28.19.104",
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://10.28.19.251:4545",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Below is my startup script:

```
java -jar /home/node1/seleniumserver/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -nodeConfig /home/node1/seleniumserver/nodeConfigChrome.json
```

I am trying to create a service using systemctl. I followed the following steps:

1) Created selenium.service in /etc/systemd/system folder.

```
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=0

[Service]
Type=simple
RestartSec=1
User=node1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/env sh /home/node1/seleniumserver/startNodeChrome.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2) systemctl daemon-reload
3) systemctl start selenium
4) systemctl enable selenium.

The service is up and running successfully.

But when I trigger the scripts from jenkins I get this error. WHICH otherwise works normally when started from terminal.

```
[ERROR] 11:59:50.026 com.ytlctest.base.WebDriverThread.getDriver() - Error creating the driver
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'node01', ip: '10.28.18.104', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '12.0.2'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
Command duration or timeout: 283 milliseconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:122) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:125) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:548) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:212) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:143) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.14.0.jar:?]
    at com.ytlctest.base.WebDriverThread.getDriver(WebDriverThread.java:131) [selfra-1.0.88.jar:?]
    at com.ytlctest.base.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:58) [selfra-1.0.88.jar:?]
    at com.ytlctest.ycms.testcase.YCMSPostpaidAccountCreation.initialiseObjects(YCMSPostpaidAccountCreation.java:73) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017) [testng-6.14.3.jar:?]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:283) [surefire-testng-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:75) [surefire-testng-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:120) [surefire-testng-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417) [surefire-booter-2.22.0.jar:2.22.0]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
```

Requesting help to solve this issue.

Comment: I think this is not a question for Stackoverflow... Maybe `Super User`, `Server Fault` or `Unix and Linux` would be better...

Comment: Maybe the problem results in different user (permissions) or the environment (variables)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
com.ytlctest.base.WebDriverThread.getDriver() - Error creating the driver
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new service: ChromeDriverService
.
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.39*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.39*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.39/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v66-68**

- Presumably you are using the latest GA build of *chrome=75.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v75**

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver v2.39* and the *Chrome Browser v75.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v75.0**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v75*** level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test` as a **non-root** user.

Comment: Thank you. I will check that. Having said that I only get error when I run as a service in CentOS